# Creation of Column

Tags: tables, multirow

I am making a table of made up of two columns, but the problem is that in the last row I have multiple column with in a single row, I don't know how to do this. I applied `\multicolumn` but it did not produce the desired result. Here is an image of the desired table.

[image]

Help me in this regard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, but in your situation I think the best is to nest `tabular` environments. Try something like this:

```
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \hline
  Heading & Heading \\
  \hline
  Item 1  & Item 2  \\
  Item 3  &
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    A & B       \\
    C & D       \\
  \end{tabular} \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
```

The above code will produce this table.
Add vertical rules as desired (although they should generally be avoided when possible).

[image]